# AJAX request using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to fire an AJAX request on the click of a button, But I am unable to trigger it on the back-end.

**index.php**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            function send1()
            {
                req.open("GET", "process.php?q=hello", true);
                req.send();         
                alert(req.responseText);      
            }
        </script>
    </head>    

    <button onclick=send1()>send</button>

</html>
```

**process.php**:

```
<?php
$new= $_GET['q'];
echo $new;
?>
```

This should give me "hello" in an alertbox why it isn't?

Comment: learn jQuery, it'll make your life simpler !

Comment: @Sourav: I would agree, but for somebody who's never used AJAX before, I think it would be beneficial to see how it all works "under the hood" of jQuery before abstracting it away.

Comment: @Sourav: I disagree. Learn Javascript, then learn how ajax works and *then* learn jquery (or some other library). There are too many people who think of this whole thing as a string of magic incantations and have no idea what's going on inside.

Comment: I don't think Mark Webber should study Aerodynamics or so ! :P

Comment: Thanx man, i was just in a hurry i guess, thanks for your advices

Comment: can you suggest me a good resource to study javascript and AJAX

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim : And so you know how your car works ? Some great people made this great tool jQuery. The first way to thank them would be by using it. Honestly, I know a lot of succesfull dev who learnt jQuery AJAX before learning pure AJAX. I took the same path, and truth be told : All my AJAX code is jQuery only.
Basically, I agree that learning plain AJAX is interesting but not necessary anymore. jQuery is indeed magic ;)

Comment: If I were a mechanic, I'd know how my car works. I wouldn't hire a web programmer who didn't know what HTTP and Javascript are but instead simply told me that he used jquery without leaning the basics because he wanted to thank the authors and because he felt it was magic.

Comment: Chill guys, OK i AM A NOOB and i know it! AND we all agree that if you want to do something you should know everything about it to have the command over it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first A in AJAX means "Asynchronous". What you need to do is listen for the readyState to change:

```
req.open(...);
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( this.readyState == 4) {
        if( this.status == 200) alert(this.responseText);
        else alert("HTTP error "+this.status+" "+this.statusText);
    }
};
req.send();
```